# Trying to delete lines from file with sed -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: macos, excel, csv, sed

I have a .csv file where I'd like to delete the lines between line 355686 and line 1048576.

I used the following command in Terminal (on MacOSx):

```
sed -i.bak -e '355686,1048576d' trips3.csv
```

This produces a file called trips3.csv.bak  -- but it still has a total of 1,048,576 lines when I reopen it in Excel.

Any thoughts or suggestions you have are welcome and appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that excel is using carriage return (\r, octal 015) to separate records, while sed assumes lines are separated by linefeed (\n, octal 012); this means that sed will treat the entire file as one really long line. I don't think there's an easy way to get sed to get sed to recognize CR as a line delimiter, but it's easy with perl:

```
perl -n -015 -i.bak -e 'print if $. < 355686 || $. > 1048576' trips3.csv
```

(Note: if 1048576 is the number of "lines" in the file, you can leave off the `|| $. > 1048576` part.)

Comment: This one worked!  Thank you very much.  Also my first experience with Perl, so thank you twice.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the osx sed implementation, however the gnu sed implementation when passed the -i flag with a backup extension first copies the original file to the specified backup and modifies the original file in-place. You should expect to see a reduced number of lines in the original file trip3.csv

Comment: Hmmm...trips3.csv and trips3.csv.bak are exactly the same, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Some incantation that should do the job (if you have Ruby installed, obviously)

```
ruby -pe 'exit if $. > 355686' < trips3.csv > output.csv
```

If you prefer Perl/Python, just follow the documentation to do something similar and you should be fine. :)

Also, I'm using one of the [Ruby one-liners](http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/ruby/ruby-one-liners.html#h5), by Dave.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to say that you need '> output.csv' to redirect stdout to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!(NR>355686  && NR <1048576)' your_file
```